# DB2 regexp_replace - replace each occurrence of a string between two characters

Tags: regex, db2

I need to  replace each occurrence of a string between two characters of a string like this:
1||5||13||18||31||32||3--6||8||21||24||37||38||3--7||16||20||22||37||38||2--6||17||21||28||31||32||8

it should become

1||5||13||18||31||32||-3--6||8||21||24||37||38||-3--7||16||20||22||37||38||-2--6||17||21||28||31||32||-8

I'm trying with this query, but it selects the first occurrence of the ||:

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('  1||5||13||18||31||32||3--6||8||21||24||37||38||3--7||16||20||22||37||38||2--6||17||21||28||31||32||8  ', '(?<=||)(.*?)(?=--)','aaa',1) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

Comment: Based on a comparison of your returned strings, this should work: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('.+(\|-).+', '$1') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to add a minus sign to every `1--2` term or to the final number in the string.  We can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` as follows:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '(\d+--\d+|\d+$)', '-\1')
FROM yourTable;
```

Side note: Pipe (`|`) is a regex *metacharacter*, and so would need to be escaped with backslash in your regex pattern, should you intend for it to be a literal value.  But, I don't think you even need to use it here.